# Using promise all with and continue process approaches

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Im using the following code which is working, as you can see I need to run `process 1 and 2` in parallel and then run `process 3 & 4` so my question is if I doing that right ? or if there an more elegant way to do it ?(I use `bluebird` and start to work with `promise` in the last 2 weeks...)

```
return Promise.all(
    //Process 1
    Validator.validate(err => {
        process.exit(1);
    }).then(() =>
        handler.init()
    ),
        //Process 2
    Parser.parse()
        .then(configObj => {
            require.cache.persist.con = con;
            return Promise.resolve();
        }, err => {
            logger.error(err);
            return Promise.resolve();
        })

).then(() => {
    //Process 3
    eventEmitter.on('App', () => {
        logger.info(`Proxy ${require.cache.persist.po}`);
    });
    //Process 4
    return process.Run().then(cp => {
        server(eventEmitter);
    });
```

Comment: To start with `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises, not multiple arguments that are promises.  Also, there's no need to do `return Promise.resolve()` from a `.then()` handler.  Just do `return`.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thank you sir, Im not sure that I fully got it, can you please add this comment as answer with example?it will be great so I can to test it exactly...

Comment: It goes like this: `Promise.all([p1, p2])`, not like this: `Promise.all(p1, p2)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 - not using the array it is bug, if yes why its currently working without the array?and why should I use return without reslove how does it know the state of reslove or reject? Thank you!

Comment: Not using the array does not actually wait for the passed promises.  It doesn't do what `Promise.all()` intends.  It's just wrong.  Any return from a `.then()` handler except returning a promise automatically becomes the resolved value of the parent promise.  That's how the promise spec is written.  So, there's no need to `return Promise.resolve();` as it does the same as `return;`.